# Dependency Definitions

Tags: c#, msbuild, dependencies

I have a C# project that needs to compile as either x86, or x64, and reference different native assemblies depending on the architecture. I realize I could include them both and assign different alias's and in each file use a #if statement, but this is quite cumbersome.

Is there any way to change a project's dependencies based on a Compiler condition?

Comment: What kind of assemblies are you referencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to leverage build configurations. You need to do a bit of manual MSBuild (.csproj) file editing, but it works really nice:

[This Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/tfsbuild/thread/62d5ef40-83a2-4ffc-ae01-c5ee6163a5c1) Has a great example of how to go about this.

Comment: Seconded. MS-Build configurations will make this pretty easy. Just open up the .CSPROJ and add some conditional item group configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That unfortunately is a PITA! I doubt that your #if statement would work (I reserve the right to be proven wrong), as each dependency needs to be a reference in the references section. The way I have worked around it is by editing each project's msbuild (.csproj) file, and creating a conditional ItemGroup that has the references for the appropriate platform.

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
   <Reference Include="System" />
   <Reference Include="System.Data" />
   <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```